# Why was conversion between Instant and Date named the way it was?

Tags: java, api-design

When `Instant` was introduced with JSR-310, convenience methods were added to perform conversion between `Date` and `Instant`:

```
Date input = new Date();
Instant instant = input.toInstant();
Date output = Date.from(instant);
```

I wonder why it was chosen to be this way instead of, let's say, having `Date output = instant.toDate()`. My guess is that it was intended to avoid making `Instant` dependent on `Date`. Is this right?

But to me it is somehow strange that you make the new class independent of the already existing one, and make the old one dependent on the newly introduce one. Is this made so because of an expected deprecation of `Date` or is there any other reason?

Comment: see [Joda Time vs Java Time](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/190891/31260). In brief, old-fashioned Java time API turned out poor design choice and designers of new API dropped it completely, without trying to polish the turd

Comment: @gnat I'm not asking about when to use one or the other, or about old Java Time at all.

Comment: "make the new class independent of the already existing one" - this is the case, one doesn't make good API dependent on a poor one

Comment: "Is this made so because of an expected deprecation of `Date`" - I suspect this is, maybe, eventually on the table.  In which case you wouldn't want to touch the new API when getting rid of the old one, no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problems with [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

- It is a mutable object
- It is not thread-safe
- cost of using it in a thread-safe manner (synchronized) is expensive

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) on the other hand is designed to be thread-safe and immutable. Making the object Immutable is by itself already a simple and inexpensive way of guaranteeing thread-safety. The Javadoc for [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) states:

> **Implementation Requirements:**
>   This class is immutable and thread-safe.

Now if you want to do something like `Instant t = Instant.from(new Date())`, that means the implementers of the API would have to introduce synchronization to guarantee the thread-safe access of the `Date` object.

I suspect that they wanted to simply have a clean break with the old ways, and avoid introducing any explicit synchronized methods. Introducing synchronized methods would have suggested that it is ok to use them. While it might be useful to have, it would be setting a bad precedent.

Instead they have chosen to keep the conversion of `Date` to `Instant` within the `Date` API, which does not document any thread-safety. Safe assumption would be that it is up to the user to synchronize access to the `Date` Object first if required to do so.